# Particle objects overlapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

So I have a subdivided Plane acting as a base and a flower object with random colour node set to it and I'm using it in a particle system to cover the entire Plane: the regrow at the exact position where another one already is even when there's empty space left. The trouble seems to be that if I set it as 'hair' the particles start overlapping before covering the entire Plane.With 'emitters' the tend not to align neither with the faces nor vertices as I want. I tried with a particle collision animation but can get to work it right.
Is there a way to prevent particle from overlapping each other and spreading uniformly over a plane(not grid).

Comment: I'm not sure you can prevent overlapping, to have more control maybe try Hair with Advanced option, then Emission > Emit From and choose Faces or Verts?

Comment: I need them to be clustered like shrubs in a jungle scene,selecting faces does not seem to work. Is there like a particle collision simulation that i can play for 5 frames and get the job done?

Answer (score 1):

On your particle settings, drop-down "Source", select "Emit from Volume", then adjust number of particles/face.